# Flip element with css continuously without action

Tags: css, animation

I want to flip an element **continuously** on the y axis from 0 to 360 degree with css **without** an action (button, hover).

Some script allow it one single time by adding a class, like: [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

And other just flip on button press (http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html) or on hover (http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php)

```
.img:hover {
   transform: rotateY(360deg);
   transition: transform 10s;
}
```

That what I tried so far, but it does only work once and only on hover...

Can you help me to get the code?

Comment: Please provide a minimum code with an example of what you managed to do so far...

Comment: Have you tried [Google](http://www.google.com/)?

Comment: Yes of course, all the links included in the question are from google

Comment: StackOverflow is a place to find solutions to specific programming *problems* you have with existing code; it is **not** a place to ask for code to be given to you.

Comment: Thats why I included my code I already tried so far now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a CSS animation with **infinite**.

```
img {
    -webkit-animation: anim 10s infinite linear;
    animation: anim 10s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}

@keyframes anim {
    from {transform: rotateY(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}
```

Comment: Seams to be a great beginning, but the animation does not work:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zoker/s3ou9v45/

Comment: Sorry I forgot the property. See the updat4d version http://jsfiddle.net/s3ou9v45/1/ If you want a constant animation add `linear`

Comment: Thank you! But the animation slows down at the end and then starts after a little pause. Can I make it fluid?

Comment: Yes add linear, like this http://jsfiddle.net/s3ou9v45/3/

Comment: Awesome! Just one last question: I dont want the image to be shown the other way around. So every time it flips, it only should show the front site

Comment: Use backface-visibility: hidden; http://jsfiddle.net/s3ou9v45/4/

Comment: But I want to display the front site instead and not only hide the backface

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64717/discussion-between-simon-arnold-and-zoker).

Answer (score 0):

is `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` the property you're looking for?

`.loopInfinitely {
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}`